# Why does IE6 give an "expected Identifier error" when using jQuery $.fn

Tags: jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-6, exception

I keep getting an expected identifier error at this line in my code =/

```
   $.fn.myPlugin = $.myPlugin;
```

any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I just found the answer here:

http://www.ventanazul.com/webzine/articles/javascript-expected-identifier-error-internet-explorer

> Some coffees later I found the
>   offending code was:
>
> var class =
>   $(this).parent().attr('class');
>
> Yep, class seems to be a reserved word
>   in Internet Explorer, thanks again
>   Microsoft for making web developers'
>   lives so difficult.
>
> I just changed the variable name to
>   fix the error, something like this:
>
> var tabClass =
>   $(this).parent().attr('class');

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it. Any of your users still using IE6 deserve such errors.